# VueFire 3 causes "do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers"

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, vuefire

I'm currently migrating a project and trying to figure out what the Vue3, VueFire3, VueX pendant to the following Vue2 + Vuexfire code is:

```
//actions.ts
[...]
  bindDummy: firestoreAction((
    { bindFirestoreRef }) => {
    return bindFirestoreRef(
         "dummyVariable",
         collectionDummy)
  }),
[...]

//state.ts
function state (): dummyState {
  return {
    dummyVariable: {}
  };
}
```

This is a setting up a binding to a variable in the VueX state called `nameOfVariableInState`. The variable will be updated automatically when the data in the firestore database changes).

I tried

```
// actions.ts
bindDummy ({ commit }) {
  const todos = useCollection(dummyCollection);
  if (todos.data) {
     commit("setDummy", todos.data)
   }
}

// mutations.ts
const mutation: MutationTree<DummyStateInterface> = {

  setDummy (state, value) {
    state.dummyVariable = value;
  },
};
```

This works to the extend that the data is displayed and automatically updated **BUT** this triggers  `Uncaught Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`. In the cryptic stacktrace `walkSet  vuefire.823f1be4.mjs:29` appears.

Comment: Title should not contain tags. For tags, you have tags section. And You know that you can use plain Firebase in your application? Funny thing is it already have a built in "VueX" solution. So I'm curious why you use VueFire3 and vuex instead of just firebase?

Comment: VueFire3 is because I want to have bindings such that my app state updates when there is a change in a firestore document. Thanks for the hint regarding the title: I'll update!

Comment: Firebase had always that "binding" it's called "onSnapshot" listener. It's opening WebSocket connection with database and updates your query result whenever data you listen changes.

Comment: And about Vuex. Just turn on persistence in your Firestore and you're good to go. You will be able to query data offline without internet connection (if you were querying before when you had internet).